# User not logged in to Firebase after reloading Angular app

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire, angular15

I have an angular app with a firbase backend. First i added firebase via Webversion 8.
Now i want to implement it with angular/fire.

This is how it added with ng add:

```
imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      enableIndexedDbPersistence(firestore).catch(e => console.error);
      return firestore;
    }),
]
```

For auth i have also an auto login function:

```
public autoLogin(): any {
  this.store.dispatch(new AppActions.Splash(true));
  const currentUser = this.auth.currentUser;
...
```

But `this.auth.currentUse`is not defined after reload.
How do i handle autologin with this version? Can't i save the user, that on next start it's saved in `this.auth`?

Comment: Restoring the user data takes a call to the server so is an asynchronous operation. To detect the result of that operation, use an auth state listener as shown in the questions I linked or in the first docs snippet of the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).